# Stripe in test mode not able to create bank account sometimes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-connect

I want to create stripe account through bank account and add bank account further on stripe in test mode.It's working but sometimes It's giving following error
"You cannot use a live bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode" while using below details.

Account Number :- 000123456789
Routing Number :- 110000000

I'm not able to get that why this is occurring sometimes.Tried to google it but did not find any solution.

Comment: I happen to remember it happening to me while i was working on Stripe Connect. Unfortunately couldn't find anything to make it a permanent success but the things are working smoothly in production for a long time now.

Answer (score 0):

Can be found [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/testing) in their documentation; to get the numbers for a specific country there's a little dropdown for you to select the relevant one. For convenience, the standard test bank account numbers below:

1. US - 000123456789
2. UK - 00012345
3. JP - 00012345

Comment: This does not answer the question. I think the user has test account numbers but the issue is that it works sometimes and sometimes it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using this one US - 000123456789 , but sometimes it won't work

Comment: are you getting the same error?
"You cannot use a live bank account number when making transfers or debits in test mode"

Comment: any other alternative ?